# Maven + Java package declaration

Tags: java, maven, package

We have a *Maven* project (packaged as JAR) with *Java* files. A new *Java* source file was recently added to this project. The path in which the Java file was added, does not match its package declaration. As expected, Eclipse shows an error in the class for the mismatch. However, Maven builds the project just fine. In the generated JAR file, the .class file is present in the path indicated by the package declaration. We tried moving the Java source file to other incorrect folders (i.e. different from the package declaration), but every time Maven builds the project fine.

So, does Maven ignore the actual directory in which the .java file is present? Does it only consider package declaration?

Comment: Please add some details like your pom (atleast its packaging like war, jar etc), folder structure, path where you added new file etc.

Comment: I've mentioned that the packaging is JAR in my question. As for the other details, sorry, but I don't see how it would help for the question. I can only provide sample values anyway, since I am working on some proprietary code.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to get idea where exactly your file is located as maven is very structure specific. But anyways, as you are saying you maven build works fine, its ok.  Some things you can do are, check whether you have properly configured maven plugin in your eclipse. THen instead of just adding project in eclipse, "import" your project as a "Maven Project" in eclipse, then it should be in sync with maven build.

Comment: @RaviK no, in this special case, importing the project won't help. Eclipse deals with source folders, Maven deals with source folders almost until the end, but passes a list of individual source files to the compiler, and that is the major difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Maven Compiler plugin internally assembles a command line call containing the arguments passed to javac, one argument per source file (using [the `sourcefiles` version of the javac call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#synopsis)). It does pass the actual source folders also for meta-capabilities like annotation processing, but when individual source files are passed to javac, these take precedence and the compiler has no efficient way to find out which file belongs to which source folder and hence can't validate the package structure.

The Maven Compiler Plugin internally uses the [Plexus Compiler API](http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-components/plexus-compiler/plexus-compiler-api/), and you can find the relevant code in these two classes:

- [plexus-compiler-api: `AbstractCompiler`](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-compiler/blob/master/plexus-compiler-api/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/AbstractCompiler.java#L188)
- [plexus-compiler-javac: `JavacCompiler`](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-compiler/blob/master/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L194)