# Why does Maven not report package errors?

Tags: java, maven

`mvn clean install` builds successfully for file

```
package maven;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

But if i change it to

```
package maveninvalid;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

it still builds successfully. Build only fails when I enter an invalid variable or something else. I was expecting it would catch invalid package errors also, why doesn't it do that?

Comment: Same thing as there I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395916/package-name-is-different-than-the-folder-structure-but-still-java-code-compiles. BTW, it's not Maven but the Java compiler that behaves like that.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: The package name must be the same where the java file is located which means the same folder on the file system. That's a basic java problem **not** a maven problem.

Comment: [Answered here in another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414638/maven-java-package-declaration)